# What legal action can be taken to stop someone placing rubbish in my mailbox?

Tags: property, new-zealand

Over the last week I noted twice that somehow a tuft of hay appeared in my mailbox at the rural property I am living in. It could be kids, or perhaps someone wanting to play or to leave me a message with meaning I have no idea of yet.

I have setup a surveillance camera registering any movements near the mailbox and so I should know who is doing it next time they do. But once I know whodoneit, what next, apart from trying to talk to them? Can placing rubbish in mailbox be qualified as an offence and prosecuted?

The jurisdiction is New Zealand, but it would be interesting to know this for the other Five Eyes alliance countries as well (US, UK, CA, AU).

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to be [trespass to land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_land) (since the mailbox is a fixture on the land) and is *actionable per se* i.e. you do not have to prove that damage was done.